# is there a way to return an ordered top 10 of a group in SOQL

Tags: soql

I want to be able to return the the top 10 groups (referred to in syntax as subgroup) of product based on sales year on year. My SOQL looks like this

```
Select fiscal_year(Despatch_Note__r.Invoice_Date__c) Year, Part_Number__r.subgroup__c, SUM(Nett_Value__c) 
From Despatch_Lines__c 
Where Despatch_Note__r.Customer_Account__r.name = 'ACME HARDWARE LTD' 
GROUP BY Part_Number__r.subgroup__c, fiscal_year(Despatch_Note__r.Invoice_Date__c) 
ORDER BY Part_Number__r.subgroup__c, Sum(Nett_Value__c) DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

My results are not what I wanted. It shows me the first 20 subgroups ordered alphabetically as opposed by nettvalue.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your problem isn't simply the list of order by columns? Just put the sum first, so

```
ORDER BY Sum(Nett_Value__c) DESC, Part_Number__r.subgroup__c
```

It works for me as expected.

Comment: You might need to have a look at the first item in my question: "top 10 groups of product based on sales year on year". I need the following: GroupL:2012:2K, GroupL:2013:100K, GroupA:2012:20K, GroupA:2013:23K which is showing sub-group ordered by Nett_value__c DESC for 2013, groups stay together and ordered by year ascending Your syntax will order it as follows: GroupB:2013:100K GroupA:2013:23K GroupA:2012:20K GroupB:2012:2K